# Why does Ionic components render the <Host> and then inside, the <TagType>, instead of just rendering the <TagType>?

Tags: ionic-framework, web-component

Refering to the documentation for a [Ionic button component](https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic/blob/master/core/src/components/button/button.tsx) I see that the component renders the `<Host>`, and then, inside the `<TagType>`. I would like to know what is the reason behind.

For example, why not just rendering the `<TagType>` ?

Along with this question, I also see that all the classes are attached to the `<Host>`, instead of to the `<TagType>`. I would also like to know what is the reason behind this. Why not adding the classes directly to the `<TagType>` ?

**This is the tsx for the Ionic button component :**

```
return (
      <Host
        onClick={this.handleClick}
        aria-disabled={disabled ? 'true' : null}
        class={{
          ...createColorClasses(color),
          [mode]: true,
          [buttonType]: true,
          [`${buttonType}-${expand}`]: expand !== undefined,
          [`${buttonType}-${finalSize}`]: finalSize !== undefined,
          [`${buttonType}-${shape}`]: shape !== undefined,
          [`${buttonType}-${fill}`]: true,
          [`${buttonType}-strong`]: strong,

          'button-has-icon-only': hasIconOnly,
          'button-disabled': disabled,
          'ion-activatable': true,
          'ion-focusable': true,
        }}
      >
        <TagType
          {...attrs}
          class="button-native"
          disabled={disabled}
          onFocus={this.onFocus}
          onBlur={this.onBlur}
        >
          <span class="button-inner">
            <slot name="icon-only"></slot>
            <slot name="start"></slot>
            <slot></slot>
            <slot name="end"></slot>
          </span>
          {mode === 'md' && <ion-ripple-effect type={this.rippleType}></ion-ripple-effect>}
        </TagType>
      </Host>
    );
```

**and This is how it gets rendered :**

```
<ion-button size="small" class="ios button button-small button-solid ion-activatable ion-focusable hydrated">Default</ion-button>

#shadow-root

<button type="button" class="button-native">
    <span class="button-inner">
        <slot name="icon-only"></slot>
        <slot name="start"></slot>
        <slot></slot>
        <slot name="end"></slot>
    </span>
</button>
```

As you can see, the classes are inserted on the Host (ion-button), instead of on the `<TagType>`. I would like to understand what benefit lies behind this decission.

---

Also, I would like to understand what is the reason for having a `<span class="button-inner">` inside the `<TagType>` (button) ? Why not just throwing the `<slot></slot>` directly into the `<TagType>` ?

I am new to Stencil and Ionic, and I am very eager about understanding the best possible way to build components. So, I would be much appreciated if anyone can kindly help me understand the reasons that lies behind this descisions!

Answer (score 0):

`Host` is used to add classes, event listeners, and attributes on the `ion-button` it self, and not any nested DOM of the component. This is because when doing things like class bindings, we only really care about the element itself, not the internals of the components. With cross-component communication and shadow DOM, it's not possible to get internal references to things like `TageType` in this situation.

And the reason for the slot is to handle cross browser differences in how text/styles are applied for buttons. More internal knowledge for us at Ionic, and not things that others need to know about.

Comment: Thanks mhartington!

I still don´t understand the slot thing inside spa.button-inner ...
I understand that each browser has its own styling for the button element.
Having that said, the button will anyway take the browser styles. For example, if Firefox gives a red border to the buttons, although the slot is inside <span class="button-inner">, the red border will be visible anyway, because the button is still there. Does this makes sense ?

Comment: By the way, isn´t a better way to apply reset styles to the button, other elements ?

Comment: One more thing. What is the button-native class on the button for ? 

<button type="button" class="button-native">

Comment: Form interaction/participation really. again more things that dev do not need to worry about.